# Gradle. How to specify shared configuration for a list of subprojects?

Tags: build, share, gradle, subproject

There are `subprojects` and `allprojects` properties, but how can I just literally list the known subset of projects? I try the following approach:

```
[project(':child1'), project(':child2')] {
    ...
}
```

which is inspired by the output of `println allprojects`:

```
[project ':stripper', project ':webui', project ':wikidigest']
```

but it doesn't work. Log output:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'projects'.
> No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.call() is applicable for argument types: (build_1ngb77rivv12hrhe33snq4jat0$_run_closure4) values: [build_1ngb77rivv12hrhe33snq4jat0$_run_closure4@38a3f968]
  Possible solutions: tail(), wait(), last(), any(), max(), wait(long)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to wrap list by call to `configure()`:

```
configure([project(':child1'), project(':child2')]) {
    ...
}
```